# Setting django permission test dynamically

Tags: python, django, templates

Is there a way to do this inside a django template? (in pseudo code)

```
  {% if perms.tasks.can_play_{{football}} %}
```

I can't think of a way to do this besides using ugly repeating code

Comment: looks like a job for a custom templatetag

Comment: Why not do it in the view and then pass a kind of sentinel value to the template? I presume you have a few possible outcomes you're interested in, say `['football', 'cricket', 'rugby']` so you could pass a context for each with a Boolean value of whether `request.user` has the perms.